Reference request: Expository paper on the use of functional analysis in differential and integral equations
Some textbooks on functional analysis do not hint that a major raison d'être of the subject is its use in the study of differential and integral equations. The reader could go all the way through without finding that out.
Probably an expository paper could remedy that deficiency.
Imagine an audience of readers who know rather little about functional analysis but whose interest in that subject might be piqued by an exposition of how it is useful in differential and integral equations.
Does such an expository article exist?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The following source has a number of chapters devoted to applications of functional analysis to differential and integral equations:

Paul Sacks "Techniques of functional analysis for differential and
integral equations" (Academic Press, 2017). Chapter 13-16 (~65 pages)
contain applications. Perhaps that's about the length of a long
expository article.

As suggested by Jochen Glueck, a nice (more advanced) followup in the realm of partial differential equations is:

Haïm Brézis "Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial
differential equations" (Springer 2011) with applications found in Chapters 8-10.

(Turned comment into answer per request)
